# Probability about event.

Tags: probability

It is found that in manufacturing a certain article, defects of one type occur with probability 0.1 and defects of a second type with probability 0.05. What is the probability that:
(a) an article does not have both kinds of defects?
(b) an article is defective?
(c) an article has only one type of defect, given that it is defective?

think I understood how to solve through formulas but not through numbers, this for the first 2 points.
the first point should be P(AandB) complement=1-P(AandB) if these two events are independent I find the intersection through the multiplication law but if they are not? also how do I understand if they are independent not having the intersection?
the second point should be P(AorB)=P(A)+P(B)-P(AandB)
for the third point I have no ideas.

Comment: Nothing in the problem statement provides any information at all regarding dependence.  As you remark, you do need that information to answer the questions.  If you want a blind guess, the writers probably intended for you to assume independence.  But you are right to feel that this is very ambiguous.

Comment: thank you for the enlightenment, i'm confused, but i think this answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the event that an article has the first type of defect, and $B$ be the event that an article has the second type of defect. We are given $P(A) = 0.1$ and $P(B) = 0.05$.

IF WE ASSUME INDEPENDENCE

a) $P\left(\lnot (A \land B)\right) = 1 - P(A \land B) = 1 - P(A)P(B) = 1 - 0.01 \cdot 0.5 = 0.995$ so 99.5% of articles have fewer than two defects.

b) $P(A \lor B) = P\left(\lnot(\lnot A \land \lnot B)\right) = 1 - P(\lnot A \land \lnot B) = 1 - (1 - P(A))(1 - P(B)) = 1 - 0.99 \cdot 0.95 = 0.0595$ so 5.95% of articles have at least one defect.

c) $P(A \triangle B | A \lor B) = P(A \land \lnot B|A \lor B) + P(\lnot A \land B|A \lor B) = (P(A \land \lnot B) + P(\lnot A \land B)) / P(A \lor B) = (P(A)(1 - P(B)) + (1 - P(A)) P(B)) / P(A \lor B) = (0.01 \cdot 0.95 + 0.99 \cdot 0.05)/0.0595 \approx 0.9916$ so approximately 99.16% of defective articles have only one defect.

IF WE DO NOT ASSUME INDEPENDENCE

Make a Venn diagram with two circles A and B. We are given that circle A occupies 10% of the space and circle B occupies 5% of the space. How much could be in their overlap $P(A \land B)$?

They might not overlap at all. Or circle B could lie entirely within circle A. Or any amount in between. So $0 \leq P(A \land B) \leq 0.05$ is all we can say.

If the amount of overlap is EXACTLY 0.5% of the space, then the events are independent (this is the formal definition of indenpendence.)

The answers to a), b), and c) will thus be ranges. For example:

a) $P(\lnot (A \land B)) = 1 - P(A \land B)$ so $0.95 \leq P(\lnot (A \land B)) \leq 1$ is the best we can do.

You should get confirmation as to whether independence of the defects is assumed before proceeding further.

Comment: many thanks, in my course i didn't do the conditional probability as in the last point of your answer, but they don't ask, hence thanks again.